# Latin hypercube sample from beta distribution with matlab

Tags: matlab, sampling, beta-distribution

I need to extract 10000 samples from a beta distribution with the help of Latin hypercube. the `lhsnorm` command only helps in case of a normal distribution. I also could not find much under `lhsdesign`. How should I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lhsdesign` to get a set of uniformly distributed numbers, then using [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) method you convert them to beta distribution. For example:

```
X = lhsdesign(10000,1);
Y = betainv(X,5,2);
histogram(Y)
```

[image: lhs beta]

Comment: thank you very much EBH for answering. However I dont quite follow the result here. the command "betainv" gives me the probability of numbers in X occuring. It doesnt really give me samples does it? the resulting diagramm on the other hand, seems correct.

Comment: @KleinerMaverick, **have a look the link above**. The idea of taking the inverse of the beta distribution it to convert uniform distribution to beta. `lhsdesign` generates numbers from U~(0,1), and you use the CDF of another distribution (which is also between 0 to 1 ), beta in this case, to get the corresponding number in it. In other words, using `lhsdesign` you randomize the probabilities to get values from beta, and with `betainv` you get the values that have this probability.